# AJAX live search max download size?

Tags: ajax, performance

I am doing a AJAX live search, showing data from a server. In some conditions, the search result is 300-600 kb of data. Is that ok in a user performance aspect? So a keystroke in the search field loads 300-600 kb of data.

Comment: That is a substantial amount of data to send every time a user presses a key.  Maybe you could have a timeout so that the AJAX request only gets sent once the user has finished typing (e.g. they haven't pressed a key in more than ~1.5 seconds).

Comment: @LukePark That is what i was worried about.. Time out is a good idea. How about cancelleing the ajax-request and do a new one on each keystroke? In that way, only 1 request is actually sent (the latest)